# What causes this ggplot2 facet bug?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm working on putting together a few R demos to demonstrate some of its features to colleagues. I particularly want to get them interested in `ggplot2` and so was putting together a simple example of faceting using `facet_grid` with the `iris` dataset.

To show them the different modes I wanted to show them what would be produced using `.~Species`, `Species~.` and `Species~Species` (a poor example I admit).

This seems to elicit some strange behaviour in `ggplot` and I was wondering why that might be. I would expect the plot below to contain points along the diagonal where the species names on each axis match one another. Instead everything is listed under `setosa` on the x-axis and then under its actual species in the y-axis.

I realise this example wouldn't arise in any realistic usage scenario, it just struck me as an interesting quirk. Why does `ggplot` behave like this?

I've also tried this with the `mtcars` dataset and get the same effect.

```
library("ggplot2")
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(Species~Species)
```

[image: ggplot faceted scatterplot showing bug]

Comment: you might be interested in `GGally::ggpairs()` ...

Comment: ha, yes I did arrive at this after thinking I should build up to scatterplot matrices!

Comment: Not sure why it happens, but I think you can get what you wanted by creating another variable `iris$Species1 <- iris$Species` and faceting on `Species~Species1`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have any information for ggplot2 to print a combination of, e.g. setosa and versicolor.

Here in this code, I reuse @Sam comment and I sample (change the order) of the new column species that we are creating. This create a *combinaison* of species. Ecologically, it's probably misleading to do this, like I did, but for sure, it prints species in the combinaisons of the different facet_grid.

```
library("ggplot2")
data(iris)
iris$Species1 <- sample(iris$Species)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(Species~Species1)
```

This is what it could look like. Again, I just created different pairs of species to print pairs in the facet grid. 
[image: R_output]

This would be an example with different years

```
iris$Year <- rep(2010:2014,dim(iris)[2])
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(Year~Species)
```

[image]